# Send a Microsoft WNS toast from linux back end

Tags: c++, linux, push-notification

I made a google search before to write here. I'm using a Linux c++ server to send notifications to Windows Phone 8.1 - silverlight. Currently, using Poco library, I developed a simple code able to send a MPNS toast.

The snippet is the following:

```
URI uri(url);
string path(uri.getPathAndQuery());
if (path.empty()) path = "/";

HTTPClientSession session(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort());
HTTPRequest request(HTTPRequest::HTTP_POST, path, HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
request.setContentType("text/xml");
request.add("X-WindowsPhone-Target", "toast");
request.add("X-NotificationClass", "2");
request.setMethod(HTTPRequest::HTTP_POST);

request.setContentLength(payload.length());
request.write(std::cout);
session.sendRequest(request)<<payload;

HTTPResponse response;
std::istream& rs = session.receiveResponse(response);
```

Now I need to update my Windows phone to the WinRT 8.1 (no Silverlight) and the notification system is WNS.

Unfortunately I haven't found enough docs to do this in a raw mode as for MPNS outside Windows. And most of examples are in C# using .NET. 
Did someone meet this problem or find docs about how to realize it?

Thank you for any suggestion.
Chris